# MySQL - определение позиции в запросе или как использовать механизм поиска по индексам btree

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

Есть запрос, выводимый на постраничном гриде, управляемый limit. При добавлении новой строки в таблицу, участвующей в запросе нужно отобразить список в данной таблице, начиная с новой записи. Запись я могу идентифицировать по уникальному идентификатору. Мне нужно найти значения start, end (limit start, end) где в диапазоне end-start будет находится искомая строка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[@KiTE](/users/2084/kite)](/users/2084/kite) дал вам правильный ответ, как это сделать средствами SQL.

Но, вообще говоря, доступ к индексам MySQL на низком уровне есть, и давно уже. Правда, мало когда нужно им пользоваться.

Подробности читать на [MySQL Handler Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/handler.html).

А вот пример. Я создал такую таблицу:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test;
+---+---------+
| a | b       |
+---+---------+
| 1 | alpha   |
| 2 | bravo   |
| 3 | charlie |
| 4 | delta   |
| 5 | echo    |
| 6 | foxtrot |
+---+---------+
```

По полю `b` создал индекс, тоже с именем `b`;

Теперь открываем хандлер:

```
mysql> HANDLER test OPEN;
```

И читаем напрямую. **Внимание**, здесь и далее `b` — это имя индекса, а не поля (блин, надо было по-другому обозвать).

Ищем нужную запись:

```
mysql> HANDLER test READ b = ('delta');
+---+-------+
| a | b     |
+---+-------+
| 4 | delta |
+---+-------+
```

Читаем две записи перед ней, в порядке индекса:

```
mysql> HANDLER test READ b PREV LIMIT 2;
+---+---------+
| a | b       |
+---+---------+
| 3 | charlie |
| 2 | bravo   |
+---+---------+
```

Курсор (позиция чтения), кстати, сместился. Мы теперь не на 'delta', а на 'bravo'. Читаем следующие четыре записи:

```
mysql> HANDLER test READ b NEXT LIMIT 4;
+---+---------+
| a | b       |
+---+---------+
| 3 | charlie |
| 4 | delta   |
| 5 | echo    |
| 6 | foxtrot |
+---+---------+
```

Поигрались, и хватит:

```
mysql> HANDLER test CLOSE;
```

Вот такой механизм. Можно использовать сравнения, можно WHERE. Работает заметно быстрее, чем SELECT.

Answer (score 4):

Если ключ автоинкрементальный, то позицию новой строки в таблице можно узнать запросом:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE id < $id_value
```

Он посчитает кол-во предыдущих записей. Это значение можно принять за позицию строки в таблице (начиная с 0).

Зная кол-во записей на страницу грида, и позицию записи в таблице базы, можно рассчитать начальную позицию страницы на которой должна находиться искомая запись.

```
$top_position = floor($row_posotion / $page_row_count)
```

Дальше можно генерить запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT $top_position, $page_row_count
```

**UPD:**
Если используется сортировка по столбцам, то, в начале, нужно узнать значения этих столбцов для искомой записи, затем, посчитать кол-во предыдущих записей. И дальше выводить страницу.

Например, если сортировать по принципу `ORDER BY filed1, field2, field3 DESC`, то:

```
-- Получаем значение сортируемых столбцов для искомой записи
SELECT filed1, field2, field3
FROM table_name
WHERE id = $id_value
INTO @filed1, @field2, @field3;
-- Получаем кол-во предыдущих записей в отсортированном списке до искомой записи
SELECT COUNT(*) - 1 /* -1 потому что искомая запись тоже попадает в COUNT(*) */
FROM table_name
WHERE
    (filed1 <= @filed1) AND
    (filed2 <= @filed2) AND
    (filed3 >= @filed3)
```

И, дальше, зная позицию:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
ORDER BY  filed1, field2, field3 DESC
LIMIT $top_position, $page_row_count
```

Как получить `$top_position`, зная `$row_posotion` (`COUNT(*) - 1`), смотри выше.

Comment: Это не подходит по ряду следующих причин:
1. Мы не знаем, не удалялись ли записи из таблицы (могут быть к примеру идентификаторы такие 1,2,3,7,8,9,11 - удалены похоже записи 4,5,6,10). Может быть порядок и другой
2. Если запрос имеет сортировку или другие составные таблицы (сортируем не по идентификатору).

на ум приходит не очень верное решение и можно сказать тупое в лоб:
select rn from (select rownumber as rn,id,остальные поля ...[наш запрос где мы проставляем номера строкам в запросе по порядку]) as d where d.id=:pnID

Comment: По 1-му пункту - все нормально. `COUNT(*)` посчитает кол-во реально существующих записей. А если используется сортировка, то нужно колдовать с условием запроса для получения `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Неудачно первый пункт описал. Классический случай для одной таблицы и Ваш ответ действительно верный. Забудем) Я другое хотел донести, мне бы внутренний механизм поиска по индексам использовать без использования сложных запросов. Да  все же не таблица у нас, а целый запрос, неизвестно какой, но имеющий идентификатор (к примеру).

Comment: Теперь даже и не знаю. Мне кажется из-за моей неправильности постановки вопроса мы ушли в сторону. Используя Ваш метод, придется писать мастер создания запросов на определение .позиции. Надо бы что-нибудь по универсальнее.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, в MySQL нет возможности прямого доступа к индексам. Они используются движком оптимизатора запросов. А создает их разработчик из расчета на условия в запросах.

Answer (score 2):

Пронумеровать строки в запросе можно следующими двумя запросами:

```
SET @n:=0;
SELECT @n:=@n+1 AS num, field1, field2, fieldN FROM table;
```

Comment: set @n:=0;
SELECT num FROM (select @n:=@n+1 AS num,id from `table` where ...) d where d.id=:pnID

Волнует как такие запросы будут себя вести на больших таблицах!? Поэтому и хочется еще проще вариант.

Comment: Вероятно, будет создана временная таблица. Нужно смотреть EXPLAIN на реальных данных.

Comment: С точки зрения производительности, отработает достаточно быстро. Но в Вашей ситуации не поможет. Нумеруются записи текущей выборки. Все равно нужно вычислять стартовую позицию.