# mysql запрос, организация архива

Tags: php, mysql

Есть следующая структура:

```
 CREATE TABLE `entries` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `pid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `tid` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `uniqid` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `last_reply` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `edited` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `edited_by` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `user_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `subject` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `category` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `hp` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `location` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `ip` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `text` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `tags` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `show_signature` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `email_notification` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `marked` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `locked` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `sticky` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `views` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `spam` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `spam_check_status` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `edit_key` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id`),
    INDEX `tid` (`tid`),
    INDEX `category` (`category`),
    INDEX `pid` (`pid`),
    INDEX `sticky` (`sticky`)
)
```

нужно получить список дат по дням (time), вместе с последним сообщением из каждого дня (subject)

```
subject time
blabla  2015-08-18
zzzzzz  2015-08-19
```

Comment: Очень похоже на http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/94250/%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%B2-sql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5 Там тоже просили последнюю запись с каждого дня.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подойдет?

```sql
SELECT e.subject, DATE(e.`time`) FROM entries e
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id) AS latestID
    FROM entries 
    GROUP BY DATE(`time`)) as dates 
        ON e.id=dates.latestID
```

Comment: То, что нужно! Подскажите пожалуйста, как еще можно выяснить страницу топика, если известен делитель т.е. 30 топиков (pid) на страницу?

Comment: Пометьте этот вопрос как отвеченный, пожалуйста

Comment: Насчет топика, лучше отдельным вопросом оформить. А можно еще поискать тут. Такого типа вопросы уже были

Comment: Посмотрите вот этот вариант: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/19946/mysql-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BD